# Loading js dynamically not reflecting

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I want to load js on the fly which is happening but the  one more js file which is included in index is loading before (file i am loading dynamically) is there way to fix the order

i am adding global.js dynamically and i want variable declared in global.js shoud be initialised before dynamicjs.DynamicJs is loaded

------------- Index.html -------------

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
       <head>
              <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
              <script src="resources/sap-ui-core.js"
                      id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
                      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.ui.commons"
                      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_goldreflection" >
              </script>
              <!-- add sap.ui.table,sap.ui.ux3 and/or other libraries to 'data-sap-ui-libs' if required -->
              <script src="js/dyn.js"></script>
              <script></script>
              <script>
                     sap.ui.localResources("dynamicjs");
                     var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idDynamicJs1", viewName:"dynamicjs.DynamicJs", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                     view.placeAt("content");
              </script>
       </head>
       <body class="sapUiBody" role="application">
              <div id="content"></div>
       </body>
</html>
```

---

```
function loadScript(url){
    var xhrObj = createXMLHTTPObject();
    // open and send a synchronous request
    xhrObj.open('GET', url, false);
    xhrObj.send('');

    var e = document.getElementsByTagName("script")[1];
    var d = document.createElement('script');
    d.src = url;
    d.type = 'text/javascript';
    d.async = false;
    d.defer = false;
    e.parentNode.insertBefore(d,e);
}


function addScriptDynamically(){
    loadScript('js/global.js'+'?scheme=12345');
}

function createXMLHTTPObject(){
    var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
    if( typeof xmlhttp == 'undefined' || xmlhttp == null )
        xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    return xmlhttp;
}

/*call function */
addScriptDynamically();
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem, the script at `"dynamicjs"` loads asynchronously and that's the problem?

Comment: Where do you load global.js?

Comment: you may load the second script in a function binded to the onload event of the first script. Syntax is different between IE and others (strange isn't it?)

Comment: dynamicjs.DynamicJs is loading before global.js. I am loading global.js on the fly . script to add js on the fly is written in  
js/dyn.js

Comment: I also tried to add below script in body which also didn't work
<script>
                     sap.ui.localResources("dynamicjs");
                     var view = sap.ui.view({id:"idDynamicJs1", viewName:"dynamicjs.DynamicJs", type:sap.ui.core.mvc.ViewType.JS});
                     view.placeAt("content");
              </script>

Comment: I know nothing about dyn.js but if you load js async you can't be sure of which file is loaded first except if you chain the async request using the onload event of the previous script

Comment: @abidibo  I have added code of dyn.js in question please check

Comment: ok I'm going home now :), but basically take a look at this file http://ajs.otto.to.it/reference/dev/ajs.js.html, the ajs.use function implements such onload behaviour even if in this case is used for another scope, tomorrow I may find more time to help you if you do not solve it before

Answer (score 0):

Why won't you try to load script with jQuery.getScript()

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getScript/

If you want compatibility with other libraries like prototype or mootools you can set `jQuery.noConflict()`